# how to call my procedure compile error occurred in java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I tried to call my oracle 11g pl/sql package through java it makes error. help me please.
this is all information about pl/sql procedure ,java programm ,and error in java.

> procedure successfully created and sql queries are tested.

```
 /*
    * create package called "final_package"
    * create PROCEDURE called "final_procedure"
    * var1 is input parameter from application
    * dbinfo is out parameter to application 
    */
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE final_package as
      PROCEDURE final_procedure(var1 in varchar2, dbinfo out varchar2);
        END final_package;                                         
        /
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY final_package IS       
         PROCEDURE final_procedure(var1 in varchar2, dbinfo out varchar2) IS
    BEGIN
       IF var1 = 'a' --input variable checking--

    ------  /* get tablespaces name, percentage */ ----
THEN 
DECLARE

tsname varchar2(500); ---- /*  put tablespaces name to this tsinfo */----
percentage varchar2(500); ---- /*  put tablespaces percentage to this tsinfo */----

--declare cursor tbspinfo--
CURSOR tbspinfo is select a.TABLESPACE_NAME as
    Tablespace,round((1-((a.BYTES-nvl(b.BYTES,0))/a.BYTES))*100,2)
    AS
    Percentages from (select TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES from
    sys.dba_data_files group by TABLESPACE_NAME) a,
    (select
    TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES from sys.dba_free_space
    group by
   TABLESPACE_NAME) b 
   where
   a.TABLESPACE_NAME = b.TABLESPACE_NAME (+)
   order by ((a.BYTES-b.BYTES)/a.BYTES) desc;


BEGIN
FOR each_data1 in tbspinfo
LOOP
-- FETCH tsname,percentage INTO tsinfo ---
    FETCH tbspinfo INTO tsname, percentage;
-- add  tsinfo INTO out parameter "dbinfo" ---
   dbinfo := tsname || percentage;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE tbspinfo;

END;
 ----   /* get database lock status */ ----
ELSIF var1 = 'b' THEN 
DECLARE
locking_id varchar2(1500);
waiting_id varchar2(1500);
status varchar2(150);
program_hold varchar2(300);
program_wait varchar2(300);

--declare cursor lock_info--
CURSOR lock_info is SELECT vh.sid locking_sid,
vw.sid waiter_sid,
vs.status status,
vs.program program_holding,
vsw.program program_waiting
FROM v$lock vh,
v$lock vw,
v$session vs,
v$session vsw
WHERE(vh.id1, vh.id2) IN (SELECT id1, id2
FROM v$lock
WHERE request = 0
INTERSECT
SELECT id1, id2
FROM v$lock
WHERE lmode = 0)
AND vh.id1 = vw.id1
AND vh.id2 = vw.id2
AND vh.request = 0
AND vw.lmode = 0
AND vh.sid = vs.sid
AND vw.sid = vsw.sid;
  BEGIN
FOR each_data in lock_info
LOOP
 -- /* put database  lock_info to varchar2 variables "locking_id,waiting_id,status,program_hold,program_wait" */ --
    FETCH lock_info INTO locking_id,waiting_id,status,program_hold,program_wait;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE lock_info;

   -- /* add  lock_info INTO out parameter "dbinfo" */ ---
    dbinfo := locking_id || waiting_id || status || program_hold || program_wait;

END;

   END IF;
   END;

   END;
   /
```

java code is

```
CallableStatement clbstmt = con.prepareCall("BEGIN final_package.final_procedure(?,?); END;");
            clbstmt.setString(1, var1);
            clbstmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            clbstmt.execute(); // error comes at this 
            abc = clbstmt.getNString(Integer.SIZE);
            abb = clbstmt.getNString(Integer.SIZE);
```

---

java error is

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "SYS.FINAL_PACKAGE", line 71
```

Comment: Describe your issue briefly ? Put the required code and java stacktrace ? Your entire procedure code won't make sense without knowing the issue ? The java error/code link not working for me

Comment: There is a problem with your `con.prepareCall`. Just put the package.procedurename and it will call the required procedure. You don't need to add the `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: @  Rachcha i checked and changed but error was same. i think error with procedure. i did little bit comment on pl/sql code please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fragment of the procedure is wrong:

```
FOR each_data IN lock_info
LOOP
 --  put database  lock_info to varchar2 variables "locking_id,waiting_id,status,program_hold,program_wait" --
    FETCH lock_info INTO locking_id,waiting_id,status,program_hold,program_wait;
END LOOP;
CLOSE lock_info;
```

Don't use `FETCH` and `CLOSE cursor` when using implicit cursor FOR LOOP statement.
The cursor for loop statement opens the cursor, fetches rows into a record variable for each iteration (each row), then closes the cursor by itself. You cannot close the cursor because it is already closed.
See this link for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#CHDBJBJE

The other problem of this code is that it fetches values from the cursor in a loop, but doesn't process them. This doesn't make sense. When the code leaves the loop, variables are undetermined - they have random values. When fetching data in a loop, the code also **must process** fetched data in this loop.
Change this code into:

```
FOR each_data IN lock_info
LOOP
--    FETCH lock_info INTO locking_id,waiting_id,status,program_hold,program_wait;
     locking_id := each_data.locking_id;
     waiting_id := each_data.waiting_id;
     status := each_data.status;
     program_hold := each_data.program_hold;
     program_wait := each_data.program_wait;

     -- Process fetched data here

END LOOP;
-- CLOSE lock_info;
```

Alternatively you can use explicit cursor loop:

```
OPEN lock_info;
LOOP
   FETCH lock_info INTO locking_id,waiting_id,status,program_hold,program_wait;
   EXIT WHEN lock_info%NOTFOUND;

   -- Process fetched data here

END LOOP;
CLOSE lock_info;
```

Comment: @ kordirko sir i did changes as above but now i got a error ``LINE/COL ERROR

32/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
32/24    PLS-00302: component 'TSNAME' must be declared
   PLS-00302: component 'PERCENTAGE' must be declared
 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
75/30    PLS-00302: component 'LOCKING_ID' must be declared
76/6     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
76/30    PLS-00302: component 'WAITING_ID' must be declared 
PLS-00302: component 'PROGRAM_WAIT' must be declared `` but i have declare them above code help me please

Comment: ok it works no declaration need thank you for support me and advises thank lot